# What are the semantics of fdatasync() when used on a directory descriptor?

Tags: linux, filesystems, posix, freebsd, fsync

Specifically, can `fdatasync` be used in place of `fsync` if I only care about the directory structure and not timestamps or other directory metadata. If it can, does it have any performance advantages?

Does POSIX define this? What do common operating systems, e.g. Linux and FreeBSD, do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it from the point of view of the VFS API, it's generally implemented as: sync content + optionally metadata. In a directory it means: sync some of children metadata + optionally it's own metadata.

However, ultimately, how to handle it, is up to the file system.

If the attributes metadata is partially decoupled like on unix filesystems, then it's probably not flushed, but on other filesystems it may be stored together, like FAT16 that stores: filename, attributes, timestamps, cluster#

From the point of view of on-disk data structures, in UNIX-like filesystems, e.g. ext4, the entries contain: inode#, entry length, type, and filename. Then it's the inode that actually stores the attributes like permissions, timestamps, etc.

BTRFS, although a lot more convoluted, still is within the tradition of unix filesystems and stores: inode key, name, and type, while the inode item stores permissions, timestamps, etc.

In this tradition also are:

- HPFS
- NTFS
- XFS
- UFS/UFS2/FFS
- MINIX
- F2FS
- JFS
- BFS
- VxFS
- ODS-2 (VMS)
- UDF

Alternative implementations:

- ReiserFS and Reiser4 (timestamps stored separately from the inode)

But even with unix filesystems which metadata gets flushed depends heavily on the implementation and only to a lesser extent in the underlying on-disk format considerations.

Comment: I would think the "data" of a directory is only the directory entries, while the access time/modification time of the directory itself is the "full metadata". The metadata of the files the directory entries refer to is neither.

Comment: The attributes, timestamps and name are part of the directory entry from the point of view of the VFS. Filesystems however are free to handle this in whatever way they see fit. The underlying data structures aren't really constrained in any way, and the metadata may be split into independent parts.

Comment: it doesn't make sense for e.g. last modification timestamp to be part of a directory entry. Since the file it refers to can be opened and modified via another entry in another directory. The filesystem would have to find all directory entries referring to the file and update them.

Comment: Well, conceptually it's reachable that way, and storing that separately is a problem only for filesystems that support hardlinks...